# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, usernotifications

I am trying to learn Swift and am going through a tutorial on push notifications.

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge , .Sound], categories: nil)
```

Is giving me the error

> "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context".

I copy/pasted this line directly from a tutorial and have found this same line used on StackOverFlow.
What am I doing wrong?
I am using Xcode 8.

Comment: Methinks this beast be yonder? ;) http://balancedcode.com/blog/files/de01930f6f2cf9e4c886531eca028cba-0.html I've had to work it up with xCode's cues for Swift 3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the documentation for `UIUserNotificationSettings`. Its signature has changed in Swift 3 as has the values for the types.

You need:

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge , .sound], categories: nil)
```

Of course if you are only supporting iOS 10 and later, then you shouldn't use `UIUserNotificationSettings` at all since it is now deprecated. Use `UNNotificationSettings` instead. But if you are still supporting iOS 9 or earlier, then using `UIUserNotificationSettings` is fine as long as you change to the updated syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot, maddy. I am aware that ios 10 and later should use the UNNotificationSettings class, but I am just getting started and was only able to find a hand-holding tutorial for ios 9. So I am going to start from there.

Answer (score 1):

`UIUserNotificationSettings` is deprecated with `UNNotificationSettings` in iOS 10, if you want to implement `UNNotificationSettings` then implement like below.

First you need to import `UserNotifications` for that.

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge , .sound]) {
     (granted, error) in

}
```

For more details on this check this [tutorial](http://justmaku.org/usernotifications-framework) by Michał Kałużny on `UserNotifications.framework`